# Why (new RegExp('[1-9]')).test('10') return true?

Tags: javascript, regex

Shouldn't the RegEx `[1-9]` mean match a number from 1 to 9, why does 10 included 0  return true?

Comment: You probably wanted `/^[1-9]+$/.test('10')`

Answer (score 7):

`/[1-9]/` regex means "The string contains any of the characters between `1` and `9`.

Since the string contains `1` it matches. The `0` doesn't matter, the string already matches.

If you want "The string consists of a single digit between 1 and 9" then you want:

```
/^[1-9]$/
```

If you want "The string contains only digits between 1 and 9 (and at least one of them)" then you want:

```
/^[1-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex's test a string, you're testing the string `10`, which consists of the chars `1` and `0`, and then test if that string contains one of the following chars: *1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9*, which it does: 1. Hence, your code evaluates to true.

If you want to check if a given number is within a given range (1 - 9), exploit the fact that JS coerces values to whatever type you need:

```
var nString = '10';
console.log(nString > 0 && nString < 10);//false
```

Or coerce explicitly:

```
var strAsNr = +(nString);
```